# Creating automated makefile to build two targets

Tags: makefile, cmake, qmake

It's been a while that I've been looking for this, I need a tool to automatically create a makefile for my project
I've seen qmake and cmake, the problem is that I have two targets (Client and server) they both use a common library (which I wrote) and I want it to create two targets for me, cmake and qmake don't do this
ty

Comment: And I can manually do this with cmake, I want a automated tool, if there is any :D

Comment: Makefiles can contain numerous targets. What exactly are you trying to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set(servers_srcs
    server.cpp
    foo.cpp
    bar.cpp
)

set(client_srcs
    client.cpp
    xyz.cpp
    abc.cpp
)
set(library_srcs
    lib.cpp
)

add_library(library ${library_srcs})
add_executable(client ${client_srcs})
target_link_libraries(client library)
target_link_libraries(server library)
```

This automatically creates your Makefile, with three targets: client server and library.

Comment: I knew this :D this process takes time to write this CMakeLists.txt if I have too many files (I do)
and I study Computer Engineering, I have a lot of Computer Assignments that require a proper Makefile, I was looking for a automated tool to create this CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Well, I don't know any tool to automatically write a CMakeLists.txt file, and I doubt that will exist: if someone were to write a tool which somehow deduce what targets you want from the code, I guess they would make it generate a Makefile.

Anyway, if you have a lot of source files, you can use a glob pattern: `file(GLOB client_srcs "client/*.cpp")`